# Декоратор функции пишет в её свойство её аргументы

Tags: javascript, декоратор

Не могу понять, почему внешний проход let..of не видит массива. Дебаггером пробежался, уже на строке с присваиванием декоратора массив пропадает из свойств work, но при этом что в первом его вызове (work (1,2)), что во втором в какой-то массив аргументы work всё таки пушатся.

```js
let work = function (a, b) {
  console.log ( a + b ); // произвольная функция или метод
};

function spy(func) {

  func.calls = [];

  return function (...args) {

    func.apply (null, arguments);

    func.calls.push (args);

  }

}
work = spy(work);


work(1, 2); // 3
work(4, 5); // 9

for (let args of work.calls) {
  console.log ( 'call:' + args.join() ); // "call:1,2", "call:4,5"
}
```

Comment: Так они пишутся в оригинальную функцию, а у вас work это уже обёртка.

Comment: П.С. В apply тоже стоит использовать args

Comment: @AlexeyTen, там тогда уж и apply не нужен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `spy` возвращает новую функцию.

В строке `work = spy(work);` ссылка на старую функцию `work` теряется.

В то же время, внутри `spy` свойство `calls` добавляется в аргумент `func`, в который передается старая функция.

Таким образом если не перетирать исходное значение все будет работать как и ожидалось:

```js
let work = function(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b); // произвольная функция или метод
};

function spy(func) {
  func.calls = [];
  return function(...args) {
    func.apply(null, arguments);
    func.calls.push(args);
  }
}
let work1 = spy(work);

work1(1, 2); // 3
work1(4, 5); // 9

for (let args of work.calls) {
  console.log('call:' + args.join()); // "call:1,2", "call:4,5"
}
```

Если же нужно, чтобы свойство добавлялось не в исходную функцию, а в создаваемую, вместо `func` необходимо добавлять его в новую функцию:

```js
let work = function(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b); // произвольная функция или метод
};

function spy(func) {
  decorator.calls = [];
  return decorator;
  
  function decorator(...args) {
    func(...args);
    decorator.calls.push(args);
  }
}
work = spy(work);

work(1, 2); // 3
work(4, 5); // 9

for (let args of work.calls) {
  console.log('call:' + args.join()); // "call:1,2", "call:4,5"
}
```